Django: Facing Issues in accessing DB and Instantiating object on app load
I want to load data from db and store it in an object and access that object from anywhere in the Django project.
Preferably using the conventional settings.GlobalSettings where settings are the django.conf.
I have a function that should run while the app starts.
How can I achieve that and is it possible?
I have been trying different implementations and getting errors like

AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'GlobalSettings'
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

I was trying to call that function as a post_migrate signal in the apps.py.
also, I was calling the settings class using from django.conf import settings and added my GlobalSettings in it and tried to load but nothing worked.
I am fairly new to this, any help would be appreciated.

You could use AppConfig.ready, but using in-memory singletons in multiprocess applications is a bad idea, because each process will have its own copy of the object. If it needs to be stored in memory you should consider memcached or redis.
